# hide application icon in menu of android phone

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am new at android. I want to hide my application icon from main menu at the run time. I believe that a manifest file is responsible for the application's presence in the main menu. But I want my application in running process while switching on android phone. But it doesn't show the application icon in menu at phone. 
Will you please tell me a solution for the same.

Comment: May I know what do you want to achieve by doing this? If you wish that only single instance of your app should be running, then there are other ways than hiding your application icon.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your application appear among the launchable applications with an icon just edit your `AndroidManifest.xml`
and remove the following:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

The following line will tell android to show the app in the launcher.

Comment: If you want a background application what you probably want is a `Service` (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) in case you need to run long tasks or a `BroadcastReceivers` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to react to specific events

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Working code Snippt :

```
ComponentName componentToDisable = new ComponentName(
                    getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Constant.main_package_name
                            + ".Splash"); // .Splash Launcher Activity
            getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    componentToDisable,
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

            finishActivities(); // Finish All activity
```